# Should I use arial-label or a label element that is visually hidden

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I am creating a search form that has two elements an input field and a button. The input field does not have an label associated with it.

To make the field more accessible I can add `<label for="searchfield">Search</label>` and visually hide it so it will e.g. be accessible for screenreaders.

I could also add `aria-label="search"` to the input field and leave the input field without an label.

I have tested with "Voice Over" on a Mac and I get the same result/output. My question is are these approaches equivalent? Or is one approach better than the other one?

Here is a [pen](http://codepen.io/ingvi/pen/524619e959228fafe17abb72ef9ca4f0).

Comment: You have two answers already, but can you offer some context? Does the rest of the site use `<label>` in its forms or `aria-label`? Do you know anything about the technology profile of users? Or the user's tech level? These things can impact your approach.

Comment: @aardrian rest of the site form fields uses `<label>` and never `aria-label`. I do not have the answer to your other questions. What do you mean by "user's tech level"?

Comment: If you are targeting users with less technical skill, and often lower-end or older equipment, then how you code things changes. For example, my parents have a dramatically different skill level than I, they do not know that you don't need to double-click links (rough example, yes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of having any knowledge of the site (how are other form fields labeled?) or the audience (what is their skill level or tech profile?), I approach these questions with a couple parameters:

1. The rules of ARIA (the [first rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1) may apply here)
2. Progressive enhancement

That being said, I often code a page without ARIA and without CSS (as that may get blocked, chunked, etc) and make sure it is accessible.

That means I code a `<label>`. Then I visually hide it. If the CSS breaks, all is still well. If the user's screen reader does not support ARIA, all is still well. As an aside, if you think all screen readers of your users support ARIA, I encourage you to do to a tech assessment of users (local blind associations are a good start in the absence of any real users). Many people still run older versions of browsers and SRs.

For sighted users, I make sure I lean on contextual clues, like a clear search icon (or the word) in the button (as Unor references). Or maybe a `placeholder` with appropriate contrast (though you could use the `<label>` as a visual placeholder with some CSS trickery to hide it on focus).

If your submit button uses SVG, then I would be folding ARIA into that given the inconsistent support around SVG alternative text methods.

FWIW, I am also not a fan of the `title` attribute, partly because of inconsistent accessible name calculation and partly because I think it looks meh.

So, to answer your questions:

> My question is are these approaches equivalent?

No, but the distance between them is shrinking.

> Or is one approach better than the other one?

That depends on context we do not have.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I have full control of the markup so the "First rule of ARIA" solves this for kinda for me.

Answer (score 3):

Using `aria-label` is preferable to relying on CSS to visually hide a `label` element.

(Related Technique: [*Using aria-label to provide an invisible label where a visible label cannot be used*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/ARIA14))

But note that [**you don’t have to provide a label**](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/62147/17023) for a search form that only consists of the search field and the submit button. Assuming that you use a button labeled with something like "Search", it already makes clear which purpose the text field has.

(Related Technique: [*Using an adjacent button to label the purpose of a field*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/G167.html))

In that case, while it doesn’t need a *label*, it should still get a *name*. One way to provide a name is to use the `title` attribute on the `input` element. The Technique [*Using the title attribute to identify form controls when the label element cannot be used*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/H65) shows this (a search form without label, with `title` attribute on `input`) in [example 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/H65#H65-ex3).

Comment: As always, I would encourage to use both `title` **and** `aria-label` for better compatibility (`aria-label` being understood only by assistive technologies while the `title` attribute give a visual tooltip on standard browsers which may be useful when  the submit button is not yet visible, using a screen magnifier for instance).

Comment: There is a difference between satisfying techniques and real-world application. OP offers no context for the users of the site, and in a vacuum blanket recommendations and spec citations can cause problems. As for`title`, I consider it a no-go by default. Regardless, more info on `title`: https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/01/using-the-html-title-attribute-updated/

Comment: @aardrian i am not advertising the sole use of the`title` attribute, but recommend its use each time we use `aria-label`. It's not a panacea, but some people like it.

Comment: Gotcha. And agreed. And I feel like you saw me tweet. Maybe somewhat related, brand new WebKit `title`/`placeholder` name calc bug: https://github.com/w3c/html-aam/issues/84 (Apologies if I am coming off hot, I know I often sound prick-ish in my brevity.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `aria-label="search"` is the correct approach, as it produces cleaner markup (i.e. no unnecessary `label` tag) and no need for CSS to set visibility of the label - like in [this example](https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/).

I believe visually hiding a `label` using CSS is a somewhat 'hacky' way to approach the problem, whereas ARIA is the standard for accessible markup, so it should be the obvious choice for situations like this.

On the other hand, it would be worth ensuring all browsers you intend to support can use ARIA correctly, and if not, it may be worth using the `label` approach to ensure compatibility across all browsers. Although, I think the support these days is pretty good, so that should not be a common scenario.